# Is it possible to create a custom table component in Adobe CQ5 where some of the cells (like the headers) are fixed?

Tags: adobe, aem, custom-component

Is it possible to create a custom table component in which only some of the cells (i.e. header cells) are fixed so that a user simply has to input their data into the already structured table? For instance, I want to put the same table on multiple pages that will have the same header cells but the body cells under each heading will be populated with varying content.

Each page would have a table for a product where there would be a header cell titled "description", a header cell titled "price", and a header cell titled "number sold", but the cell information for each of these categories would be different based on the product. The component would consist of the table with the headings, and the user would only have to go in and add his information about the product into the predetermined cells.

Answer (score 0):

Many things are possible with cq5, and what you are asking can certainly be done.

Although I'd have the input for the component set through a dialog rather than having the client mess with text components inside the cells. But that choice kinda depends on the requirements. It shouldn't be hard to make such a component.

Comment: So I can fix the cells in the dialog editor and they should stay fixed when the user brings up the table on the page to edit it?

Thanks for the response, by the way

Comment: You have 2 viable options in my opinion. 1. you put the properties that the customer needs to fill in in a dialog, and place these properties directly in the table inside your component (e.g. in your component do something like this : ... <td>${fn:escapeXml(properties.price)}</td> ...) This way your customer does not have to mess with cells directly. 2. Instead of using a dialog, include text/textandimage component directly in your table cell (this allow your customer to abuse these components though

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I think the dialog option is best, but how do I fix the cells in the dialog so that when the user opens the dialog to edit, the table headings are already filled in yet still editable like the rest of the remianing empty cells? This way he could have a table of fixed headings but could use the rich text functions of the dialog editor to add another row or column if necessary, change a fixed heading, make it bold, etc. He could choose to use the predefined headings and input his info under them but also adjust the entire table as he sees fit.

Comment: You can't have it all. If you put the entire table inside a rich text you can't prevent your customer from messing with the headings. If these are your requirements, build a component that can write out the fixed part (with fixed properties at fixed locations) and still have a rtf for other additional flexibility. Although this can be a seperate component on your page.

Comment: HowI wish i could. I was able to create what I wanted, more or less. I added a "cq:template" node to the component to specify the heading cells so that the user has them when he opens the dialog to edit. He can change them if he wants, but they are implanted by default in the component. However, this default table (w/ fixed headings) only appears when the component is manually dragged to the page from the sidekick. When I try to code for the component in the content.jsp, it bypasses the template node and renders as a blank table. Do you have any idea why this is happening? Thank you again

Comment: You have used the cq:template for a component. This is mainly used for a page. I don't know your exact structure, so I'm guessing here. I suspect you have something like a "product" page component where you include your "product details" component which constains the your table and your setup. I suspect this content.jsp is part of the page component? Well you basically have to put the definition of your component on the template for the page aswell. This way the component will already be there with the table when you create the page.